# using 'sed' to replace the first occurrence of an open/close XML tag with another tag name

Tags: macos, shell, sed, replace

provided I have an XML that looks as follows:

```
<a>
<b>...</b>
<c>...</c>
<c>...</c>
<d>..</d>
</a>
```

How can I tell sed (on a mac) to ONLY change the first occurrence of <c>...</c> into <e>...</e>, while still preserving what was in between (\1) the opening and closing tags?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
sed '1,/<c>/s/^<c\(.*\)c>$/<e\1e>/'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed like this:

```
sed -E '1,/<c>.*<\/c>/s#<c>(.*)</c>#<e>\1</e>#' inFile
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/fzsZg5

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it